# Print Controller Variable to View Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, orm, eloquent

Been working in this for Hours, I want to print the Controller Variable in the Views. Here is my Code:

Controller:

```
        $mydate=Carbon::now()->addHours(8);
        $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

        $mydata = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->get();



        return View::make('Home')->with($mydata);
```

And here is my View

```
       <div> {{$mydata}} </div>
```

I'm just getting error with this code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$mydate=Carbon::now()->addHours(8);
    $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

    $mydata = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->get();



    return View::make('Home',['mydata' => $mydata]); //just a different way to send vars to view
```

*view:*

instead of

```
<div> {{$mydata}} </div>
```

use this

```
<div> {{print_r($mydata)}} </div>
```

Comment: if variable value is string type then it is working with simple {{$mydata}} too now. May be changed in latest version of laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<div> {{ print_r($mydata->toArray())}} </div>
 //or
<div> {{ print_r($mydata)}} </div>
//try this to know if you have got data in your $mydata
<div> {{ $mydata[0]->id }} </div>  // id- a field name can change if u dont have one
```

or try this in your controller

```
$this->content = View::make('Home', array('mydata' => $mydata));
```

Comment: There is no eroor when I delete my Views code, so it means its means that the problem is just in the view

Comment: is your view getting displayed??

Comment: Tried the controller solution, no errors but nothing is showing.

Comment: The view is getting displayed if I dont include the the codes above

Comment: does your  `$mydata` got values??